# How to create and run angular 2 program in windows platform?

Tags: javascript, npm, typescript, angular

I have installed npm and related package like typscript, angular 2
        etc. but not able to run angular 2 in browser. So anyone please walk me through the process that I can create and run angular 2 in windows platform.

Comment: Following the [5 min quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) instructions (which include Windows instructions) didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

As requested use the following line:

```
npm install angular2
```

You can append flag --save to store the name of the module in an existing package.json if appropriate.

after following line

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of good angular2 demos available on github which are working fine on windows. For example: https://github.com/meandemo/ng2-demo.git

Good luck with your learning journey.